# C++ array elements comparison

Tags: c++, dev-c++

I want to have a comparison in two `arrays`, I tried in this way:

```
#include <iostream> 

using namespace std; 

int main(){ 
int v1[10] = {1, 5, 77, 3, 4, 0, 2, 6, 8, 9}; 
int v2[10] = {20, 18, 2, 3, 4, 0, 1, 9, 6, 8}; 
int i,l,c=0,n=0; 

//comparision
for(i=0; i<10; i++) 
{ 
    for(l=0;l<10;l++) 
    { 
        if ((v1[i] == v2[l]) && (c==0)) 
        { 
            cout << v1[i] << " e " << v2[l] << " are common" << endl; 
            c = 1; 
        } 
        else if((n==0) && (l==10)) 
        { 
            cout << v1[i] << " it s in only one array" << endl; 
            n = 1; 
        };
    } 
    c=0,n=0; 
} 

system("pause"); 
return 0; 
}
```

But it seems not working for the uncommon element, the program show me only the common elements but not the uncommon. I can't understand why.
Someone can help me?

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: Please put more detail so that anyone can help.

Comment: 1) explain in more detail 2) Use a debugger before post, so you can see your logic running and most of times you'll see the problem.

Comment: **Indentation** please. This code is a wreck and really hard to follow because of it.

Comment: 3) Indent your code so that it is easy to follow.

Comment: @PaulB I edited the indentation in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `l` can never be 10, which is the condition to show the unique element. The loop will stop at 9.

I'd suggest you only use one variable to flag the uniqueness. For example:

```
bool found = false;
for(i = 0; i < 10; i++) 
{ 
    for(l = 0; l < 10; l++) 
    { 
        if ((v1[i] == v2[l])) 
        { 
            cout << v1[i] << " e " << v2[l] << " are common" << endl; 
            found = true; 
        } 
        else if(!found && l==9) 
        { 
            cout << v1[i] << " it s in only one array" << endl; 
        }
    } 
    found = false; 
}
```

Also if one wanted to change the code a bit the check can be only after the inner loop:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
    bool found = false;
    for(int j = 0; j < 10; j++){ 
        if ((v1[i] == v2[j])){ 
            cout << v1[i] << " e " << v2[j] << " are common" << endl; 
            found = true; 
        }
    }
    if(!found){
        cout << v1[i] << " is in only one array" << endl; 
    }
}
```

Comment: I recommend putting `bool found = false;` at the beginning of the first loop body, then you don't need to repeat it at the bottom.

Comment: @Barmar That's true! Edited accordingly.

Comment: Thank you so much @Felix i tried your solution with  l = 9 but i don't understand a thingh or i was not able to explaine it, if i want to found the found element in the 2 arrays until 10 cycle, why  l = 9? maybe i wrong at start with my for cycle i must to use i <=10 and j <= 10 ? thank you.

Comment: @Amiga500 Arrays in C++ start from zero. So the tenth element is element at index 9. We set the flag ´found´ to be true if the similar element is found. So we know if ´found´ is still false after every element, there must be no match. Does that help? Did it work?

Comment: @Felix it's all ok, just in your first solution i obtain at the end of the program i obtain "92 is only in one array", but the number 92 i ever putted in my arrays, so where is the problem? have you the same like me? thank you in advance